# Do continuous functions with small uniform norm preserve order?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, order-statistics

Consider a sequence $x_1,\dots,x_n\in [0,1]^d$. Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Moreover, let $f\in\mathcal{F}$ such that
$$f(x_1)< f(x_2)< \dots < f(x_n).$$

I'm wondering if there is any condition over $\mathcal{F}$ and $\delta>0$ so we can conclude that for all $g\in\mathcal{F}$ with $\|f-g\|_{\infty}<\delta$,
$$g(x_1)< g(x_2)< \dots < g(x_n).$$

I think this may be true if we take $f,g$ lipschitz and something like $\delta=\min_{i,j}\|x_i-x_j\|$, but I'm not sure.

Thank you very much.

**Edit:**  I <strike>relaxed</strike> changed the condition
$$f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)\leq \dots \leq f(x_n),$$
to
$$f(x_1)< f(x_2)< \dots < f(x_n).$$

Comment: I don't think so. If $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then you can find functions $g$ arbitrarily close to $f$ such that $g(x_1) > g(x_2)$.

Comment: @MartinR True, I edited the question. What if I change the condition to $<$ instead of $\leq$?  Thank you.

Comment: Now something like $\Vert f-g \Vert_\infty < \frac 12  \min(f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k))$ should work.

Comment: In fact, you didn't relax the condition... you strengthened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *strictly* increasing values $f(x_1) < f(x_2) < \cdots < f(x_n)$ you can define $\epsilon = \frac 12  \min(f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k))$. Then $\Vert f-g \Vert_\infty < \epsilon$ implies
$$
 g(x_k) < f(x_k) + \epsilon \le f(x_{k+1}) - \epsilon < g(x_{k+1})
$$
for $1 \le k < n$.

This works for all bounded functions $f, g$ from an arbitrary domain to $\Bbb R$, the continuity is not relevant here.

Requiring Lipschitz continuity for $f$ does not help because that does not guarantee  a minimum distance between the $f(x_k)$.

Comment: Is there a way to choose $\epsilon>0$ not depending on $f$? That is, $\epsilon>0$ such that for any pair $f,g$ with $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$, then $f(x_1)<\dots<f(x_n)$ if, and only if, $g(x_1)<\dots<g(x_n)$ ?

Comment: @rico:  No, that is what I meant with the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the case $n=2$ that can be easily generalized.

*Under the stronger condition $f(x_1) \lt f(x_2)$ the result holds.*

For the proof, consider the map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\psi : & (\mathcal F, \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & f & \longmapsto & f(x_2) - f(x_1) \end{array}$$

$\psi$ is linear, continuous as for $f, g \in \mathcal F$

$$\vert \psi(f) \vert \le 2 \Vert f \Vert_\infty.$$

Therefore if $\psi(f) = a \gt 0$,

$$\{g \in \mathcal F \mid \psi(g) \gt a/2\}$$ is open being the inverse image under $\psi$ of the open subset $(a/2,\infty)$. This allows to get the desired conslusion.